Select min or max based on where duplicate value exists
I'm trying to find a way to select the minimum or maximum from a range of data based on these conditions:

Group by columns: location_cd, machine_cd, product_cd, temperature
If multiple rows have the same value of MAX(created_timestamp) then select the row with the MIN(data_source)
Otherwise, just select the row with the MAX(created_timestamp).

Sample table: sold_out



location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
temperature
data_source
created_timestamp




0012345678
1234567890
123456
1
3
2024/06/10 15:30:15


0012345678
1234567890
123456
1
4
2024/06/10 15:30:15


0012345678
1234567890
654321
0
3
2024/06/10 14:50:15


0012345678
1234567890
654321
0
4
2024/06/10 15:00:15



Expected output :



location_cd
machine_cd
product_cd
temperature
data_source
created_timestamp




0012345678
1234567890
123456
1
3
2024/06/10 15:30:15


0012345678
1234567890
654321
0
4
2024/06/10 15:00:15



I tried this, but it is not working.
SELECT machine_cd,
    location_cd,
    product_cd,
    temperature,
    case WHEN exists(
        SELECT machine_cd,
            location_cd,
            product_cd,
            temperature,
            created_timestamp,
            COUNT(*)
        From sold_out
        group by machine_cd,
            location_cd,
            product_cd,
            temperature,
            created_timestamp
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) THEN MIN(data_source) ELSE MAX(created_timestamp) END
FROM sold_out
GROUP BY machine_cd,
    location_cd,
    product_cd,
    temperature


If you provide the DDL+DML i.e. a DBFiddle you make it much easier for people to assist.

@Dale K Thanks for your comment. I have updated the data sample for the second desired result.

Like all TOP 1 per group problems you can just create a row number partitioned and ordered as per your requirements and use that to filter the rows you need e.g.
with cte as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by location_cd, machine_cd, product_cd, temperature order by created_timestamp desc, data_source asc) rn
    from TestData
)
select location_cd, machine_cd, product_cd, temperature, data_source, created_timestamp
from cte
where rn = 1
order by location_cd, machine_cd, product_cd, temperature, data_source, created_timestamp;

DBFiddle

Thank you for your help. I'm glad this issue has been resolved, and I feel like I've learned some cool things about SQL.
